# Apache keeps forcing non-UTF-8 character set

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, encoding, utf-8

I am having a character encoding problem with a web page that works well in local but once uploaded to a remote server doesn't works properly.

I have a simple textarea that I use to update a MySQL database row with some UTF-8 encoded text. The pages are HTML5 and use utf-8 encoding.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
...
```

Also my database and the tables are encoded with **utf8 database charset** and **utf8_general_ci database collation**.

When I submit the form and see the updated textarea with info from the database, I see it with messed up character. In local (but connecting to the same remote database), everything is fine.

This is the textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="info" required><?=htmlentities(getInfo($mysqli));?></textarea>
```

And the function to output the result

```
function getInfo ($mysqli) {
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT info FROM settings LIMIT 1")) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $result->free();
    }

    return $row["info"];
}
```

I have the impression like my remote web server is overriding the charset informations somehow, so I tried adding to my .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

What could be the possible causes that still cause my text to display like this?
[image]
This is how I see it in local, SAME code and SAME remote database.
[image]

In chrome developer tab, under Network, it seems Response headers are correct:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Have you tried database connection in `UTF - 8`

Comment: If you mean using $mysqli->set_charset("utf8") I just tried with no luck.

Comment: whatever place you are making db connection set this `mysqli_set_charset($yourConnection, "utf8");`  It will be called every time you `insert`/`fetch` your records and try this with new records.

Comment: As I said I tried and didn't work :(

Comment: Try this with new records insert and also double check your table charset and collation

Comment: still doesn't help..

Comment: Perform `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to show us the hex for the naughty character. That will help decide whether the data is wrong in the database or the data is being processed incorrectly after fetching from the database.